# Generating beans for wix.xsd with jaxb fails since schema seems to be invalid

Tags: jaxb, wix, xsd, wix3.7

I'm using JAXB (from Java 7) to generate beans for the schema definitions of WiX. But this generation fails since the wix.xsd (from the source tree of WiX 3.7) contains some regex with word boundary and other delimiters which are not allowed in a regex inside an xml schema definition.

Is there any way to proceed besides changing the schema definitions?

Comment: In a twitter conversation Rob Mensching mentioned yesterday that the xsd files from the source tree were compiled into a final format. But I haven't found these final xsds yet, so I couldn't check if they still contain these invalid regex patterns.

Comment: as a workaround I have removed all pattern elements from the wix.xsd now. This should be no problem in my case since I only want to generate wxs files and not validate them. But I'm still hoping for a proper solution